# Wix Bundle, MsiPackage InstallSize attribute limited to 2,147,483,647 (need 15gb)

Tags: wix, burn

One package in our installer bundle downloads data from our server and then uncompresses it.  The size of this data is 15gb.

I want to put this value into the Add/Remove programs size column.

The InstallSize attribute would appear to do what I want however, when I set it "15050494389" I get the following error:

The MsiPackage/@InstallSize attribute's value, '15050494389', is not a legal integer value.  Legal integer values are from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.

Ignoring why I would want a negative value, is there a way of setting the value correctly?  Is there some setting I need to tell burn that I want values bigger then 32bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not supported today in WiX v3.8. You can file a [feature request](http://wixtoolset.org/issues/).

Answer (score 1):

I thought this property would be set automatically? Either way, it looks like you need kilobytes, not bytes for this field. Try 15728640.

Are you referring to ARPSIZE or something else btw?

- [Add or Remove Programs Entries](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/com-expression-syntax-miscellanea/add-or-remove-programs-entries)
- [Configuring Add/Remove Programs with Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I tried adding ARPSIZE but it seemed to make no difference at all.  I added it in wix script for the msi that does the downloading.

Comment: The setting is in bytes and there is no way (I am aware of) to change it to kilobytes or even gigabytes ... would be nice!